# How to declare array as any: when using UseState hook?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I am trying to declare the useState array as any type but I'm not sure how? This is what i've tried

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState(any[])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useState` takes a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html). You can do this

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState<any[]>([])
```

Refer this for more : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/8a1b68be3a64e5d2aa1070f68cc935d668a976ad/types/react/index.d.ts#L844

Answer (score 2):

Like this: `const [files, setFiles] = useState<any[]>([])`