# Getting "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined" when trying to access properties of an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a function that grabs data from a local JSON file and renders it. Simple stuff. I do the fetch request within the useEffect hook to fire it only on the first render. Once the data is fetched, it sets it in `employees`. Once in `employees`, I use another useEffect to set some other states with data from `employees`.

```
  const [employees, setEmployees] = useState<any>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("data.json", {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (data) {
        setEmployees(data["employees"]);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(employees)
    /* set some other state */
  }, [employees]);

/*render list of employees*/
```

My problem is, I can't actually access the properties within `employees`. When I console.log the contents of `employees`, this is what I see, an array of objects

```
[
  {
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Doe",
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Jane",
    "last_name": "Doe",
  }]
```

So to access the properties of the object, i've tried this

```
employees[0]["first_name"]

employees[0]."first_name"

employees[0][first_name]

employees[0].first_name
```

In the first two, I get this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'first_name')
```

While in the last 2 I get this error

```
Cannot find name 'first_name'
```

If someone could tell me how to properly access my data it would be much appreciated!

Edit: I'm working in Typescript if that changes anything

Comment: First guess, it seems your console log is giving object with 2 strings. What you need is key/value pair. So remove "" from the first_name, last_name.

Comment: is employees defined yet? try this:        employees ? employees[0]["first_name"]:null

Comment: Both `employees[0]["first_name"]` and `employees[0].first_name` should work. Maybe you want to access the first item (`[0]`) when there is no data (i.e. before `setEmployees` is called )?

Comment: @charly1212 i just tried that, and I still get the type error above so it looks like employees is indeed defined.

Comment: @DenisStojkovićStole how can I "un-string" the keys if I can't access the properties though? The data comes from a JSON file so the keys have to be strings to begin with.

Comment: `employees?.[0]?.first_name` should be a safe way to access this property if it exists. What could be happening is that your data isn't actually a javascript object and just a string that you got from your JSON. `setEmployees(JSON.parse(data["employees"]))` could fix it

Comment: add `if(employees && employees.length>0)` That will at least be better code and make the error go away. Then you just need to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
const [employees, setEmployees] = useState<any[]>([])
```

link:
[How to declare array as any: when using UseState hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62418171/how-to-declare-array-as-any-when-using-usestate-hook)